# What does `openssl x509 -hash` calculate the hash of?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

In the following command, `openssl x509 -in example.crt -hash -noout` outputs `8927dc31`.

```sh
openssl req -out example.crt -keyout example.key -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -x509 -subj '/C=US/CN=example.com' -days 3650
openssl x509 -in example.crt -hash -noout  # 8927dc31
```

[openssl-x509(1)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-x509.html) just says it's the "hash" of the subject name.

```
       -subject_hash
           Outputs the "hash" of the certificate subject name. This is used in OpenSSL to form an index to allow certificates in a
           directory to be looked up by subject name.

       -issuer_hash
           Outputs the "hash" of the certificate issuer name.

       -hash
           Synonym for "-subject_hash" for backward compatibility reasons.
```

- What is the "hash" function? (sha1? md5?)
- What exactly is "the subject name"? (`Subject: C = US, CN = example.com` in `openssl x509 -in example.crt -text`?)
- Can I reproduce the same hash value with the command line?

Comment: I think it's only used for creating filenames for a directory of trusted certificates.

Comment: Yes, and for O(1) trusted-certificate lookup when verifying the issuer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first 4 bytes (8 hex-letters) of the sha1 hash of the ASN.1-encoded subject value (issuer value for `-issuer_hash`).

You can reproduce the hash with the following command:

```sh
echo '
  310b30 09060355
04060c02 75733114
30120603 5504030c
0b657861 6d706c65
2e636f6d
' | xxd -r -p | sha1sum
# => 31dc2789c1e1182fbfbb64ee0a0c9a6e11276f97  -
```

The first 4 bytes is `31dc2789`. If the CPU on which `openssl` runs is little-endian (including x86_64),
openssl inverts the bytes [1] (`31 dc 27 89` → `89 27 dc 31`) then prints `8927dc31`

The ASN.1-encoded subject value `310b30...` is found by `wireshark example.crt`.

[image: Finding out the ASN.1-encoded subject value with Wireshark]

If the subject is empty (`-subj '/'`), the hash is the sha1 of empty data.

```sh
openssl req -out example.crt -keyout example.key -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -x509 -subj '/' -days 3650
openssl x509 -in example.crt -hash -noout  # eea339da
sha1sum </dev/null
# => da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  -
# da 39 a3 ee ... -> flip bytes: ee a3 39 da: eea339da
```

[1]: This looks unnatural to me. I consider [this](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1m/crypto/x509/x509_cmp.c#L203-L205) should have been `ntohl()`ed.

Comment: The ASN.1-encoded subject value is also visible by `openssl x509 -in example.crt -outform DER | od -w32 -t x1z`. But it seems, must need the correct DER layout to extract the sequence of bytes correctly.